# Google escaped fragment vs encoding

Tags: seo, fragment

When we have a url containing a hash bang google will use the escaped fragment as described here: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

e.g:

http://mysite.com/search#!potato

becomes:

http://mysite.com/search?_escaped_fragment_=potato

**But what about encoding?**

How will google behave if my url is like this:

http://mysite.com/search#!?q=potato&p=23

Will it just be:

http://mysite.com/search?_escaped_fragment_=?q=potato&p=23

or something like this

http://mysite.com/search?_escaped_fragment_=%3Fq%3Dpotato%26p%3D23

**UPDATE:**

This guy has a different tak on the quistion - but still no answer:
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/webmasters/21O7HlAB90A/wfCdo3KcmskJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second option. You have to URL parameter encode the content otherwise the & will cause it to be a new parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the response,

Are you tellings me that I (the website) show encode the url like this:

http://mysite.com/search#!%3Fq%3Dpotato%26p%3D23

because that will produce rather ugly urls

Comment: No. Just the fragment parameter contents have to be encoded

Comment: In the example above it's only the fragment parameter that has been encoded.
Hvor would google react if the url was like this: http://mysite.com/search#!?q=potato&p=23

Comment: When you are using characters that cause encoding issues the only real way to find out is to try it and test. If Google correctly deals with encodings then assume all after the #! Will be URL parameter encoded in the fragment parameter your server receives. Your server logs will confirm what the bot is looking for.

Comment: The information here isn't entirely correct. There are special escaping rules for the escaped_fragment part. For example, `&` is escaped, but `=` isn't. See the specification here https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification . This means you probably can't use your stock urlEncode() to do this.